# The weakest topology on R such that all polynomials (in one variable) are continuous, is hausdorff.Prove or disprove

Tags: general-topology

My attempt:
The weakest topology on R is {phi, R} on which every f: R to R is cont. But that is not hausdorff.

Comment: Given $x\ne y$, consider a polynomial function $f$ with $f(x)\ne f(y)$.

Comment: f(x)=x is such polynomial.

Comment: Then what is next?

Comment: You need to clarify your question: do you use the "new" topology on both the domain and the codomain, or only on the domain?

Comment: If the polynomials are continuous in some topology, then for any $a< b$ we can consider the disjoint open sets $(a,\frac{a+b}{2})$ and $(\frac{a+b}{2},b+1)$. This sets are open due to the fact that $f(x)=x$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

If we give $\mathbb{R}$ the minimal topology $\tau$ such that every polynomial $f: (\mathbb{R}, \tau) \to (\mathbb{R}, \tau_e)$ is continuous, where $\tau_e$ is the usual, Euclidean topology on the reals, then the situation is clear: because $f(x)=x$ is a polynomial, $\tau_e \subseteq \tau$ and because the Euclidean topology does make all polynomials continuous so $\tau \subseteq \tau_e$ and $\tau=\tau_e$, not very interesting.

We can also give $\mathbb{R}$ the minimal topology $\tau$ such that every polynomial $f: (\mathbb{R}, \tau) \to (\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is continuous: this is also not very interesting as $\tau=\{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset\}$, the trivial topology always works and is clearly minimal.

The cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the Zariski topology on the reals: the closed sets are generated by the zero-sets of polynomials. And this topology is not Hausdorff. Maybe the OP had that one in mind?